# Hiding products without thumbnail in WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce, product

I use importer which imports thousands of products to the shop. Although I must insert picture and description for the product before I want to sell the item.

I would like to hide product from the store at all IF there is no thumbnail image assigned. This way new products appear to the shop only after I have set the thumbnail image.

I tried this in header.php, but did not work:

```
 <?php if($_product->getImage() && $_product->getImage() != 'no_selection'){
?>
 <style>
  /* Css to hide Featured image Div */
 </style>
<?php
}?>
```

This gave me error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getImage() on a non-object

Is there any quick way to hide WordPress WooCommerce products from the Shop page, if they do not have a thumbnail picture placed?

Thanks

Comment: use [`woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail()`](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail/)

Comment: doesn't work :( Fatal error: Call to a member function woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail() on a non-object in

Comment: `$_product`  has the problem there. it's not an object.check `var_dump ($_product);` and see what it shows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_product_query`** action, hook that will change the shop query and will not display on shop page products without an image, this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $query ) {

    $query->set( 'meta_query', array( array(
       'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
       'value' => '0',
       'compare' => '>'
    )));

}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works on WooCommerce 2.6.x and 3.0+

Comment: I want to hide all products in woocommerce which have no image. So is it possible?
Thanks

Comment: @Chetan It should be… Check in your database (in wp_postmeta table) for this products to see, if there is some meta_key / meta_value that is convenient for that…

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do, and it worked perfectly for me in my /wp-includes/functions.php file. Thanks! I will probably move it into a custom plugin so I can activate/deactivate it easily, but for now this works great, thanks!

Comment: Actually, it works, but only after a different sort is selected. Each time the page is loaded, it shows everything. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious...

Answer (score 0):

Woo-commerce usually inserts a placeholder picture on products which don't have a thumbnail picture. What you can do is target products which don't have a thumbnail using Jquery easily.

on my website it puts an imame named "placeholder.png" which will be in site_url()."/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/images/placeholder.png", site url which is your website's url.

enqueue a javascript to your theme or create a child theme and add it in the functions.php file.

here goes the code.

*hideproduct.js*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery(".products a img.woocommerce-
            placeholder").parents(".product").css("display","none");

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could save yourself a lot of struggle and import your products initially with the `post_status` set to `draft`, which will result in not showing them on the front page. Then, every time you add an image to your product, which I assume you do via the WP backend, you "publish" your product, since you have to save it anyway.

If you have a separate import-script for images, you can set the `post_status` to `public` from there.