# Sort products without thumbnail in WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, sorting, woocommerce

I would like to create a function that instead of hiding the products without thumbnails, would be ordered in such a way that the products with the highlighted image appear first on the shop page while those without the highlighted image appear at the end. I tried to modify an already [existing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884498/hiding-products-without-thumbnail-in-woocommerce-shop-page):

```
    function woocommerce_product_query( $q ) {
        $q->set( 'meta_key', '_thumbnail_id' );
        $q->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        $q->set('order', 'DESC');
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'woocommerce_product_query' );
```

I tried adding `orderby`  to this already existing function too but nothing happens, keep hiding the products from me.

In this photo the function only hides the products without thumbnail.
I don't know how to solve ...
[image: Shop page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented the code but the sorting is done alphabetically. While I would like to sort by product entry date:

```
function my_shop_custom_products_query( $q ) {
        $q->get( 'meta_key', '_thumbnail_id' );
        $q->set('orderby', 'meta_value');
        $q->set('order', 'DESC');
        $q->set( 'meta_query', array(  'relation' => 'OR', array(
            
           'orderby' => 'meta_value',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
           'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
     //  'value' => '0'       
  
        ),
  array(
     'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
           'compare' => '>=',
       'value' => '0',       
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
       'order' => 'DESC'
  )),
); 
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_shop_custom_products_query' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, in `value` you need to enter the current ID of the placeholder image. But this sorting made the loading of products much worse ;/ I have about 25k products...

```
function my_shop_custom_products_query( $q ) {
    $q->set( 'meta_key', '_thumbnail_id' );
    $q->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    $q->set('order', 'DESC');
    $q->set( 'meta_query', array( array(
       'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
       'compare' => '!=',
       'value' => '31594'
    )));
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_shop_custom_products_query' );
```